# Saving and restoring mutiple window layouts

Tags: project

I'm using the latest version of Emacs on Linux. I'm having trouble saving and restoring various window layouts and buffer states across multiple projects.  For example:

- Project A: 3 window layout / 3 specific buffers
- Project B: 4 window layout / 4 specific buffers
- Project C: 2 window layout / 2 specific buffers

I've been using revive.el and I like that it saves and restores not only the window layout, but also the files I was working on in that project, including the last point I was at in those files. Unfortunately, revive only seems to recall just one window layout for one set of files (i.e., toggle on or off).

Looking for a complete solution, I found [windows.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowsMode) (seemingly bundled somehow with revive) but I'm not exactly clear what it does. It's not on melpa, looks rather dated, so I assume it's not even maintained. Then I found workgroups.el but it gives me all kinds of warnings after installing from melpa. I also tried workgroups2 but I have similar issues with warnings. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [desktop-save-mode](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html)

Comment: Yes. Took me a while to get it working the way I wanted but it works reasonably well.